# Google Maps Autocomplete keypress simulation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, buddypress

I currently have the following function that is running when Ajax has finished running on my page, which then loads in text (for now) and then brings up the autocomplete dialog.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    jQuery('#facetwp-location').val('Richmond, Vic'); // populate the input box
    google.maps.event.trigger( document.querySelector('#facetwp-location'), 'focus', {} ); // force the autocomplete to show
    });

</script>
```

I need to do the following:

1. Get the user location information from BuddyPress Xprofile field (which will replace the pre-written text)
2. Automatically load the first item in the autocomplete list (ie simulate a keydown and Enter on the list that is displayed

Once again, my jQuery skills are lacking, and need a bit of assistance to complete this function.

I have worked on it, and so far have this - but it is still not complete

```
function get_user_location_for_facet_load(){
if (is_page(2101)) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() { 
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
jQuery('#facetwp-location').val('<?php
$user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
echo xprofile_get_field_data('Suburb',$user_id);
?>'); // populate the input box
$('#facetwp-location').focus();
google.maps.event.trigger( document.querySelector('#facetwp-location'), 'focus', {} ); // force the autocomplete to show
$( ".pac-container .pac-item:first" ).promise().done(function() {
google.maps.event.trigger( document.querySelector('.pac-container .pac-item'), 'focus', {} ); 
 google.maps.event.trigger(document.querySelector('.pac-container .pac-item'), 'keydown', {
        keyCode: 13
    });

//var txt = $('#facetwp-location').val();
//alert(txt);
});
});
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Not sure if I am any closer, but if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking correct, but try to enclose your code in [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
$(function() { // enclose your ajax complete in document ready function
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
       jQuery('#facetwp-location').val('Richmond, Vic'); // populate the input box
       google.maps.event.trigger( document.querySelector('#facetwp-location'), 'focus', {} ); // force the autocomplete to show
    });
});
```

Alternatively, try to use [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) on input and trigger google maps in its handler like

```
$(function() { // enclose your ajax complete in document ready function
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
       jQuery('#facetwp-location').val('Richmond, Vic').keypress(function(){
          google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'focus', {} ); // force the autocomplete to show
       });
       jQuery('#facetwp-location').trigger('keypress');
    });
});
```

**Updated** with google code,

```js
 $(function() {
   var lat = -33.8688,
     lng = 151.2195,
     latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
     image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

   var mapOptions = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
       zoom: 13,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     },
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latlng,
       map: map,
       icon: image
     });

   var input = document.getElementById('facetwp-location');
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
     types: ["geocode"]
   });

   autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
     infowindow.close();
     var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
     if (place.geometry.viewport) {
       map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
     } else {
       map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
       map.setZoom(17);
     }

     moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
   });

   $("#facetwp-location").focus(function() {
     selectFirstResult();
   });


   function selectFirstResult() {
     infowindow.close();
     $(".pac-container").hide();
     var firstResult = $('#facetwp-location').val();
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({
       "address": firstResult
     }, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
           lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
           placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
           latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

         moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
       }
     });
   }

   function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
     marker.setIcon(image);
     marker.setPosition(latlng);
     infowindow.setContent(placeName);
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }

   $('#facetwp-location').trigger('focus');
 });
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCsaZtFeCU6YCKI_1D_tJ73JzARq9j6zaY&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="facetwp-location" value="Richmond, Vic" type="text" size="50" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This has added no real functionality change, and does not include any simulated keypresses to allow the auto-complete to submit and search

Comment: Try my updated answer and alternative option. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: This still does not submit a keypress to the browser, which is what I am trying to without the user having to press anything. This is not close any other suggestions regarding the Google Maps Autocomplete API and what needs to be done to get it to submit (ie submit a down arrow keypress and then an ENTER to select the first location in the list)

Comment: I have worked on it, and so far have this - but it is still not complete

Comment: This is what I can get going so far - I want the input to submit automatically, so it can refresh the page [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0JQYTaNoGSVZzV1Uk10LTFCYkU/view)

Comment: Thanks for your help Rohan, but I've been asked to no longer put this into the site. Thanks for your help.